# Hedge Fund Leverage - FX exposure

Tags: fx, leverage, hedge, funds

how is leverage calculated for hedge funds that follow a global macro strategy. Specifically interested in knowing the FX exposure- forwards or spots. If it’s just Longs+Shorts, then leverage would be very high? Thanks

Comment: "how is leverage calculated" - by whom? PBs? Regulators? Methodologies might differ and there's no guarantee they're sensible (e.g. regulatory calculation of the leverage of an options strategy might simply aggregate the exposure across strikes even for a limited risk structure such as a call or put spread).

Comment: thanks. want to understand calculation of gross leverage per the AIFMD directive for FX forwards or spots, not FX options.

Comment: There are a few bits of info here https://www.linklaters.com/en-us/insights/publications/aifm/leverage